# Ошибка (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

я встретился с такой ошибкой:

> Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead."

Я никак не могу решить эту проблему, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: По-моему там все ясным английским языком написано почему не работает и как исправить.

Comment: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C